# php - How to put a dot before last two number

Tags: php

In PHP I can do the following to dot on last 2 number places;

For example: `$test1 = 146209; echo $test1;`

Result show: `1462.09`

Comment: checkout number_format()

Comment: So many possibilities... either treat the variable as a string and do something as ridiculously simple as using `substr`, or divide by 100 and use `number_format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

divide by 100

so

```
echo $test1/100;
```

Comment: Simplest way indeed but due to the nature of floating point numbers, don't be surprised to sometimes get more than 2 decimals..

Answer (score 3):

Good old printf to the rescue:

```
printf("%.2f",$test1/100);
```

Comment: Why do you need `printf()`?

Comment: To make sure it always has 2 decimal places, otherwise `5200` will display as `52` instead of `52.00`

Comment: Oh yes of course!! I should got up and got a shower before attempting to answer this question.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a number format and divide by 100 easily enough:

```
$test1 = 146209; 
$deci=$test1/100;
echo number_format($deci,2);
```

Short version looks like:

```
echo number_format($test1/100,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$paymentAmount = 100;
$floatAmount = (strpos($paymentAmount/100, '.') !== false)? 
floatval($paymentAmount/100):floatval(($paymentAmount/100).'.00');

echo $floatAmount; // 1.00
```